# Why does this bootloader crash?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, bootloader, osdev

I've looked more into creating my own bootloader, rather than using grub. I soon came up with this:
It takes care of switching to 32bit pm, it loads my kernel from the disk & it jumps to it to execute it.

- I'm catting my kernel & my bootloader like this: `cat boot.bin kernel.bin > img.bin`
- I'm assembling my bootloader like this: `nasm -f bin kernel/arch/$ARCH_TARGET/boot/boot.s -o boot.bin`
- I'm compiling my kernel like this: `i686-elf-gcc *.o -Ttext=0x0 -o kernel.bin -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib -lgcc`

(`*.o` are all compiled C files which I compile like this: `i686-elf-gcc -c file.c -o file.o -std=gnu99 -ffreestanding -O2 -Wall -Wextra`

This is my bootloader code:

```
[org 0x7c00]
[bits 16]

xor ax, ax
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax

; load kernel
mov bx, 0x1000
mov dh, 10 ; reading 15 sectors should be enough ._.
mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE]
call dsk_load
call load_kernel

dsk_load:
    mov [SECTORS], dh
    mov ch, 0x00 ; C = 0
    mov dh, 0x00 ; H = 0
    mov cl, 0x02 ; S = 2

    next_group:
        mov di, 5 ; retry 5 times

    again: 
        mov ah, 0x02
        mov al, [SECTORS]
        int 0x13
        jc maybe_retry
        sub [SECTORS], al ; set remaining sectors
        jz done
        mov cl, 0x01 ; read sector 1
        xor dh, 1 ; next head
        jnz next_group
        inc ch ; next cylinder
        jmp next_group

    maybe_retry:
        mov ah, 0x00 ; reset drive
        int 0x13
        dec di
        jnz again
        jmp dsk_err ; we've tried too many times, give up

    dsk_err:
        mov bx, BOOTLOADER_SIG
        call print
        mov bx, DISK_READ_FAIL
        call print
        jmp $

    done:
        ret

; print string
print:
    ; print loop
    print_loop:
        mov ah, 0x0e
        mov al, [bx] ; load current character
        cmp al, 0
        je print_return ; return when finished
        int 0x10 ; print character
        inc bx ; next character
        jmp print_loop

    print_return:
        ret

load_kernel:
    ; If all that went well, we can switch to protected mode
    cli
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor]
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 0x1
    mov cr0 , eax
    jmp CODE_SEG:init_32_pm ; make a far jump

    [bits 32]
    init_32_pm:
        mov ax, DATA_SEG
        mov ds, ax
        mov ss, ax
        mov es, ax
        mov fs, ax
        mov gs, ax
        jmp 0x1000 ; call kernel
        jmp $

    ; our beloved gdt
    gdt_start:
        gdt_null: ; null descriptor
            dd 0x0
            dd 0x0
        gdt_code: ; code segment descriptor
            dw 0xffff ; limit (bits 0-15)
            dw 0x0 ; base (bits 0-15)
            db 0x0 ; base (bits 16 -23)
            db 10011010b ; 1st flags, type flags
            db 11001111b ; 2nd flags, Limit (bits 16-19)
            db 0x0 ; base (bits 24 - 31)
        gdt_data: ; data segment descriptor
            dw 0xffff ; limit (bits 0-15)
            dw 0x0 ; base (bits 0-15)
            db 0x0 ; base (bits 16 -23)
            db 10010010b ; 1st flags, type flags
            db 11001111b ; 2nd flags, Limit (bits 16-19)
            db 0x0 ; base (bits 24 - 31)
    gdt_end:
        gdt_descriptor:
            dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1 ; gdt size
            dd gdt_start ; gdt start address

            ; some handy constants
            CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start
            DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start

    BOOT_DRIVE db 0
    SECTORS db 0
    BOOTLOADER_SIG db "------ NubelaOS bootloader ------", 0x0d, 0xa, 0
    DISK_READ_FAIL db "An error occurred while loading the kernel! Please restart your computer.", 0x0d, 0xa, 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

Booting it into Qemu makes it go in a "boot loop", by rebooting constantly

Comment: Can you try to pinpoint the location where the crash happens? For example, try putting `jmp $` at points in the assembly code and try to find which instruction causes the issue

Comment: Also, why `-Ttext=0x0`? Aren't you loading at 0x1000?

Comment: The offending instruction seems to be `call 0x1000` at the `init_32_pm` function

Comment: Probably not cause of your error but you should write `BOOT_DRIVE` only after initialising `ds` to zero.

Comment: Where is your stack?

Comment: could the stack be an issue? I'm not using it in this code

Comment: Since the `call` instruction writes to the stack, you are using it and not setting it up properly is an issue.

Comment: Why is -Ttext=0x0? Are you sure that the call instruction is the culprit? Did you try to put forever loops (breakpoints) in your kernel (I assume you wrote in C)  and check whether it the problem still exists?

Comment: Also, it seems like you're calling `load_kernel` recursively. Is this correct?

Comment: I noticed that. Updated my code

Comment: Bochs has a nicer debugger than qemu, which should help you pinpoint where the code goes wrong.  If all you can do is observe the overall behavior and stare at the code itself, it's going to be very frustrating - instead, find a way to get more precise information.

Comment: As others said -Ttext=0x0 should be `-Ttext=0x1000` since that 's where you loaded things. You should set SS:SP (stack) before you do a disk read in real mode (a stack at 0x8000:0x0000 would suffice)&you should set ESP to some place in memory before calling into the C code. (setting ESP to 0x90000 would suffice). Something else-you're jumping to 0x1000 and not calling and if your kernel does a return there is no place to return back to. Maybe you meant `call 0x1000`.. You should set BOOT_DRIVE to DL after setting DS. This isn't an [mcve] and this code works with a test kernel I had in C.

Comment: I hope your kernel binary file doesn't exist 15 sectors (15*512 bytes) and hopefully you ensured the entry point for your C code is the first function output to the binary file. Without an [mcve] this could be a problem in your kernel as well (and you don't show that ciode.